# HTML5 Server Sent Events (SSE) with JSON and PHP

Tags: php, json, html

I'm trying to set up a HTML5 Server Sent Event that updates a webpage with JSON data.
I've checked out a ton of info sites and tutorials online but there doesn't seem to be any that are written for complete beginners (like me).

I've also checked answers to similar questions on this StackExchange but still cannot work this out.

I could only get an basic example from 'w3schools' to work, although this doesn't use JSON.

I'm hoping someone can show me how I can get HTML5 Server Sent Events to work with JSON data.

The files which I got working are as follows:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>


<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
    };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

   $time = date('r');
   echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
   flush();
?>
```

An example of the type of JSON data I'd like to use with SSE is as follows:

```
{"employees":[
    {
        "firstName":"John", 
        "lastName":"Smith",
        "age":"25"
    },
    {
        "firstName":"Sally", 
        "lastName":"Simpson",
        "age":"24"
    },
    {
        "firstName":"Pete", 
        "lastName":"Daltry",
        "age":"30"
    }

]}
```

I have had some success with jQuery and the JSON file above using the following script:

```
<body>

<p id="team"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/
jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("team.json", function(data){
        $.each(data, function(){
            $.each(this, function(key, value){
                $("#team").append(
                "First Name: " + value.firstName + "<br>" +
                "Last Name: " + value.lastName + "<br>" +
                "Age: " + value.age + "<br><br>"
            );
        });
    });
});
});

</script>

</body>
```

However, I cannot get SSE to work with JSON data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the data coming from server is in string format you can send a json string from the server. The code will be (server side code).

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$data = array(
    'firstName'=>'Test',
    'lastName'=>'Last'
);
$str = json_encode($data);
echo "data: {$str}\n\n";
flush();
```

and on client side.

```
var source = new EventSource("events.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    var jdata = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log(jdata);
};
```